# Macros Runtime Error 1004: Method 'Cells' of object '_global' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have just started learning Macros. When I click on the Macros button to create a report, I get the error

> method 'cells' of object '_global' failed.

The code is:

```
Workbooks(watP).Activate
Cells(1, 1) = "List"
```

And I am getting the error in this line: `Cells(1, 1) = "List"`

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: This [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) will get you started. If you follow what has been advised there you will not face these problems :)

Comment: May be its due to worksheet...try this Workbook(watP).worksheets("Your sheet name).cells(1,1)="List"

Comment: Agree with @SiddharthRout that you should avoid `select` but in this case I don't think that's causing the problem.You either need a sheet reference (either `activesheet.cells(1,1) = List` or as above `sheets(sheetname).cells(1,1) = List`, or try `Range("A1") = List`

Comment: @SpencerBarnes: Feel free to disagree but I guess you missed my answer there?

Comment: @SiddharthRout correct, sorry!!

Answer (score 1):

`Workbooks(watP).Activate` activates the workbook with a name, in the variable `watP`. The active worksheet is not mentioned. To see the `ActiveSheet`, run this:

```
Workbooks(watP).Activate
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
```

Then, most probably somehow the cell `A1` of the worksheet, displayed in `MsgBox()` is not to be written into, because it is not the correct one you are expecting. Try this:

```
Sub TestMe()
    
    Dim wbkName As String
    Dim wksName As String
    
    wbkName = "Book1"   'change it to the real name of the workbook
    wksName = "Sheet5"  'change it to the real name of the worksheet
    
    Workbooks(wbkName).Worksheets(wksName).Cells(1, 1) = "List"

End Sub
```

After some time, when you start feeling nice and accustomed to VBA, you may take a look at one of the best practices, discussed here - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/35864330#35864330).

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response. This is the entire code:

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I entered MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name, but got a blank popup. I also added the TestMe() function, but I am not sure of the worksheet. Can you please help more here?

Comment: Here is complete code:
    
    Workbooks(watP).Activate
    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
    Workbooks(watP).Worksheets("Index").Cells(1, 1) = "List"
    
    
    Sheets("Index").Select
    Columns(1).AdvancedFilter action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=Range("b1"), unique:=True
    
    
        Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:= _
        xlTopToBottom
    Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Comment: @AayushVohra - try to do it on an new Excel workbook. Concerning the worksheet - you may use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name_of_worksheet")` instead of the `ActiveSheet`. Instead of "Name_of_worksheet", write the real name, usually "Sheet1".